# How to save 1 min video named date and time continuously with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing, video-recording

I want to repeatedly every minute to create a new video file named with the current date and time saved to directory path.

In the below code all it can do is a single video of 1 min length.

```
import cv2
import time 
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from os import path



cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
   print("Error reading video file")
fps = 24
res = '480p'
def change_res(cap, width, height):
   cap.set(3, width)
   cap.set(4, height)
STD_DIMENSIONS =  {"480p": (640, 480),"720p": (1280, 720),}
def get_dims(cap, res='720p'):
   width, height = STD_DIMENSIONS["480p"]
   if res in STD_DIMENSIONS:
       width,height = STD_DIMENSIONS[res]
   change_res(cap, width, height)
   return width, height
PREFIX = 'Cam'
EXTENSION = 'avi'
file_name_format = "{:s}-{:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M-%S}.{:s}"
date = datetime.now()
today=time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
file_name = file_name_format.format(PREFIX, date, EXTENSION)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter ("/home/Desktop/CAM/"+str(today)+"/"
                       +file_name, fourcc, 24.0, get_dims(cap, res))

start_time = time.time()
while (time.time() - start_time) < 60:
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   if ret == True:
       out.write(frame)
       cv2.imshow('CAM', frame)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap everything in a `while True:`, like so:

```
import cv2
import time
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from os import path


while True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if (cap.isOpened() == False):
       print("Error reading video file")
    fps = 24
    res = '480p'
    def change_res(cap, width, height):
       cap.set(3, width)
       cap.set(4, height)
    STD_DIMENSIONS =  {"480p": (640, 480),"720p": (1280, 720),}
    def get_dims(cap, res='720p'):
       width, height = STD_DIMENSIONS["480p"]
       if res in STD_DIMENSIONS:
           width,height = STD_DIMENSIONS[res]
       change_res(cap, width, height)
       return width, height
    PREFIX = 'Cam'
    EXTENSION = 'avi'
    file_name_format = "{:s}-{:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M-%S}.{:s}"
    date = datetime.now()
    today=time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    file_name = file_name_format.format(PREFIX, date, EXTENSION)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter (file_name, fourcc, 24.0, get_dims(cap, res))

    start_time = time.time()
    while (time.time() - start_time) < 5:
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       if ret == True:
           out.write(frame)
           cv2.imshow('CAM', frame)
       if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break

    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Or instead of `while True:` you can add a counter in the loop and e.g. break out of the loop when the counter reaches a certain value etc.

Comment: Surely there are some things there that don't need to be done every minute (or in your case 5 seconds)... say re-opening the camera, re-defining those two functions and all those constants, ....

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, much appreciated. As Dan said now I'm trying to figure it out how to keep the camera live streaming and the odd thing of the fact that saved videos are played on fast forward. I'm newbie and the initial code is what I could do until now.

Comment: what do you mean with 'keep the camera live streaming'? On my setup the window with the video stream always stays open. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Hmm.. Then probably is something that I'm not doing properly as my camera window closes and reopen between records.